# $G$ is a group. For any $x, y \in G$, show there exists $z \in G$ such that $y = xz$.

Tags: group-theory

The question is in the title. My intuition says this is true at least in finite groups. Can it be proven for all groups?

PS: Lesson learned is that (1) reduce the problem to a system you know well (probably arithmetic) (2) over reliance on visual thinking is a weakness.

Comment: It is true for all groups. Hint: multiply both sides of the equation $y=xz$ on the left by $x^{-1}$ to see what $z$ must be.

Comment: Pick $z = x^{-1}y$.

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now. I should've seen you need to "solve" for $z$. I was thinking visually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $z = x^{-1}y$, then the desired equality holds.